# How to get the badge when validating HTML in the W3C validator?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I'm trying to validate a 4 page website in the W3C validator.

When I validate my CSS page, I get code for the web seal badge.
When I validate my 4 separate HTML pages, they all validate but offer no code for a badge.

How do I get the badge?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but getting the badge is *really* not important these days. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 17):

If it isn't offering you one then you are, presumably, writing HTML 5 (one is provided for HTML 4 and XHTML 1 documents).

See [this interview](http://html5doctor.com/html5-check-it-before-you-wreck-it-with-miketm-smith/) with Michael[tm] Smith:

> No, there won’t be a Valid HTML icon any time soon and likely not
>   ever. The reason is basically that “This is valid” icons/badges
>   promote the idea that there’s significant value in making public
>   claims of pass/fail document-conformance requirements in standards.
>
> But the HTML5 checker is by design not intended to encourage anybody
>   to use it as a means to make public assertions of simple pass/fail
>   conformance of any documents to any particular specifications; it’s
>   intended solely as a checker — for people to use to catch unintended
>   mistakes in documents and fix them — not as a pass/fail certification
>   mechanism.
>
> There won’t be any proper Valid HTML5 icon forthcoming, so if you’d
>   like to use one in your content, you’ll probably need to create one on
>   your own.

So you don't get the badge because one doesn't exist.

Comment: That sounds right but why do they offer one for CSS? Maybe CSS is either right or wrong but HTML has more grey areas?

Comment: @user3425506 — No. Just changes of opinions over time.

Comment: @user3425506 - there is no CSS (3) badge either: https://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/Icons
It seems they stopped this entirely. Which makes sense, because the whole badging stuff can be faked.

Answer (score 4):

Although I agree with Mike Smith's quote from [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36383974/295789), that HTML Validation doesn't need a badge for certification purposes, I do believe that badges are still useful in a monitoring sense.

So, maybe the badge doesn't go in the footer of a website, like some e-commerce anti-fraud badge, but perhaps that badge gets used to keep developers aware of the status of their product?

I could see it being useful when setting [deployment-goals](/questions/tagged/deployment-goals) in README's or as a continuous integration tool when automatically updated with tools like [consistently.io](https://consistently.io).

For example:

[image: Deployment Goals]